# How to calculate causal inference in bayesian networks

Tags: bayesian, causality, bayesian-network

As beginner I am reading [this Bayesian Networks example](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html).

I have also read [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209363/how-to-do-calculate-both-causal-and-diagnostic-inferences-simultaneosly-in-bayes).

[image]

It calculates $P(S=1,W=1)$, the result is $0.2781$. I tried to expand the equation, but getting incorrect result:

$P(W,S) = P(W|S) \cdot P(S)$

$P(W,S) = ( P(W|S,R) \cdot P(R) + P(W|S,\bar{R}) \cdot P(\bar{R}) ) \cdot P(S)$

$P(R) = P(R|C) \cdot P(C) + P(R|\bar{C}) \cdot P(\bar{C})$

$P(R) = 0.8 \cdot 0.5 + 0.2 \cdot 0.5 = 0.5$

$P(\bar{R}) = 1 - 0.5 = 0.5$

$P(S) = P(S|C) \cdot P(C) + P(S|\bar{C}) \cdot P(\bar{C})$

$P(S) = 0.1 \cdot 0.5 + 0.5 \cdot 0.5 = 0.3$

$P(W|S,R) = 0.99$

$P(W|S,\bar{R}) = 0.9$

$P(W,S) = (0.99 \cdot 0.5 + 0.9 \cdot 0.5) \cdot 0.3 = 0.2835 \neq 0.2781$

What is wrong with my calculation? May I start with $P(W,S)$ for the $P(S=1,W=1)$?

Then how to solve $P(W=1) = 0.6471$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The short answer

Intuitively, the issue is the fact that $P(S)$ and $P(R)$ are **only independent when you condition on $C$**, so $P(S,R) \neq P(S)P(R)$.

This was your mistake - you accidentally implied $P(S,R) = P(S)P(R)$ in one of your calculations.

I'll show you where this happened exactly below, but that is what motivates the approach of the other answers - Using marginalization as they do is a good way to ensure you don't accidentally imply that $P(S,R) = P(S)P(R)$

### Where you got tripped up in your calculations

Let's see where this applies in your calculations.  Let's take this equation from your post:

$$P(W,S) = ( P(W|S,R) \cdot P(R) + P(W|S,\bar{R}) \cdot P(\bar{R}) ) \cdot P(S)$$

**This is the problem**, because you calculate $P(S)$ separately, and then multiply it through, resulting in some cases of $P(S)P(R)$ where you really meant $P(S,R)$

Let's go back to the beginning and walk through the equations, using your notation, to see how this could have been avoided.

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(W,S) &= P(W | S) P(S) \\
&= P(W | S) P(S | C) P(C) + P(W | S) P(S | \bar{C}) P(\bar{C})
\end{aligned}
$$

This looks similar to what you did, but the crucial point is to avoid "factoring out" $P(S)$ and calculating it separately.  Instead of doing that, let's go deeper and condition on $R$ and $\bar{R}$.

I'll start with the first term:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(W | S) P(S | C) P(C) 
&= P(W | S, R) P(S | C) P(R | C) P(C) \\
&+ P(W | S, \bar{R}) P(S | C) P(\bar{R} | C) P(C) \\
&= (0.99)(0.1)(0.8)(0.5) + (0.9)(0.1)(0.2)(0.5) \\
&= 0.0396 + 0.009 \\
&= 0.0486
\end{aligned}
$$

Following the same logic, the second term is as follows

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(W | S) P(S | \bar{C}) P(\bar{C}) 
&= P(W | S, R) P(S | \bar{C}) P(R | \bar{C}) P(\bar{C}) \\
&+ P(W | S, \bar{R}) P(S | \bar{C}) P(\bar{R} | \bar{C}) P(\bar{C}) \\
&= (0.99)(0.5)(0.2)(0.5) + (0.9)(0.5)(0.8)(0.5) \\
&= 0.0495 + 0.18 \\
&= 0.2295
\end{aligned}
$$

Add these together, and you get $0.2781$!

### Bonus Round: Sprinklers on a rainy day (i.e., the importance of conditional independence)

If you intuitively understand that $P(S,R) \neq P(S)P(R)$, then you can skip this last section.  However, I think it's a fun example for building intuition, so I'll go into a bit of detail.

So what's the difference between $P(S,R)$ and $P(S)P(R)$?  Let's calculate it, starting with the latter.

$$P(S)P(R) = (0.3)(0.5) = 0.015$$

Now let's calculate $P(S,R)$ to show the difference.  We'll do so by conditioning on $C$ and $\bar{C}$.

Note that since $S$ and $R$ are conditionally independent on $C$, we can say that $P(S,R | C) = P(S | C) P(R | C) P(C)$

The rest is a fairly straightforward calculation:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(S,R) &= P(S,R | C) P(C) + P(S,R | \bar{C})P(\bar{C}) \\
&= P(S | C) P(R | C) P(C) + P(S | \bar{C}) P(R | \bar{C}) P(\bar{C}) \\
&= (0.1)(0.8)(0.5) + (0.5)(0.2)(0.5) \\ 
&= 0.04 + 0.05 \\ 
&= 0.09 
\end{aligned}
$$

In this case, there's some intuition - The chances of it both raining and sprinkling at the same time are lower once you take into account the conditional dependence.  This is because **it's most likely to rain on cloudy days, but that's precisely when the sprinkler is very unlikely!**

Answer (score 1):

Just use marginalization:
\begin{eqnarray}
p(W) &=& \sum_S \sum_R \sum_C p(W,S,R,C) \\
&=& \sum_S \sum_R \sum_C p(W \mid S,R)p(S\mid C)p(R \mid C) p(C) \\
&=& \sum_S \sum_R p(W\mid S,R) \bigg[\frac{1}{2}p(S \mid C=1)p(R \mid C=1) + \frac{1}{2} p(S\mid C=0)p(R \mid C=0) \bigg]
\end{eqnarray}
If you plugin the numbers from the CPTs carefully, you will get p(W=1)=0.6471.

Same for your first question: $p(W,S) = \sum_R \sum_C p(W,S,R,C)$ and just do the summations for all possible combinations of ${R,C}$.

Comment: But I still want to know what is wrong in my calculation, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

By using marginalization, as mentioned by @YBE,

\begin{align}
P(W=1,S=1) & = \sum_R \sum_C P(C,S=1,R,W=1) \\
 & = \sum_R \sum_C P(R \mid C) P(S=1 \mid C) P(W=1 \mid R,S=1) P(C) \\
 & = \sum_R \bigg[ P(R \mid C=1) P(S=1 \mid C=1) P(W=1 \mid R,S=1) P(C=1) \\
 & \quad + P(R \mid C=0) P(S=1 \mid C=0) P(W=1 \mid R,S=1) P(C=0) \bigg] \\
 & = \sum_R \bigg[ 0.5 \cdot 0.1 \cdot P(R \mid C=1) P(W=1 \mid R,S=1) \\
 & \quad + 0.5 \cdot 0.5 \cdot P(R \mid C=0) P(W=1 \mid R,S=1) \bigg] \\
 & = 0.5 \cdot 0.1 \cdot \bigg[ P(R=1 \mid C=1) P(W=1 \mid R=1,S=1) \\
 & \qquad + P(R=0 \mid C=1) P(W=1 \mid R=0,S=1) \bigg] \\
 & \quad + 0.5 \cdot 0.5 \cdot \bigg[ P(R=1 \mid C=0) P(W=1 \mid R=1,S=1) \\
 & \qquad + P(R=0 \mid C=0) P(W=1 \mid R=0,S=1) \bigg] \\
 & = 0.5 \cdot 0.1 \cdot ( 0.8 \cdot 0.99 + 0.2 \cdot 0.9 ) +  0.5 \cdot 0.5 \cdot ( 0.2 \cdot 0.99 + 0.8 \cdot 0.9 ) \\
 & = 0.2781
\end{align}

And,

\begin{align}
P(W=1) & = \sum_S \sum_R \sum_C P(W=1,S,R,C) \\
 & = \sum_S \sum_R \sum_C P(W=1 \mid S,R) P(S \mid C) P(R \mid C) P(C) \\
 & = \sum_S \sum_R \bigg[ P(W=1 \mid S,R) P(S \mid C=1) P(R \mid C=1) P(C=1) \\
 & \quad + P(W=1 \mid S,R) P(S \mid C=0) P(R \mid C=0) P(C=0) \bigg] \\
 & = \sum_S \sum_R \bigg[ 0.5 \cdot P(W=1 \mid S,R) P(S \mid C=1) P(R \mid C=1) \\
 & \quad + 0.5 \cdot P(W=1 \mid S,R) P(S \mid C=0) P(R \mid C=0) \bigg] \\
 & = \sum_S \bigg[ 0.5 \cdot P(W=1 \mid S,R=1) \bigg[ P(S \mid C=1) P(R=1 \mid C=1) \\
 & \qquad + P(S \mid C=0) P(R=1 \mid C=0) \bigg] \\
 & \quad + 0.5 \cdot P(W=1 \mid S,R=0) \bigg[ P(S \mid C=1) P(R=0 \mid C=1) \\
 & \qquad + P(S \mid C=0) P(R=0 \mid C=0) \bigg] \bigg] \\
 & = \sum_S \bigg[ 0.5 \cdot P(W=1 \mid S,R=1) \bigg[ 0.8 \cdot P(S \mid C=1) + 0.2 \cdot P(S \mid C=0) \bigg] \\
 & \quad + 0.5 \cdot P(W=1 \mid S,R=0) \bigg[ 0.2 \cdot P(S \mid C=1) + 0.8 \cdot P(S \mid C=0) \bigg] \bigg] \\
 & = 0.5 \cdot P(W=1 \mid S=1,R=1) \bigg[ 0.8 \cdot P(S=1 \mid C=1) \\
 & \qquad + 0.2 \cdot P(S=1 \mid C=0) \bigg] \\
 & \quad + 0.5 \cdot P(W=1 \mid S=1,R=0) \bigg[ 0.2 \cdot P(S=1 \mid C=1) \\
 & \qquad + 0.8 \cdot P(S=1 \mid C=0) \bigg] \\
 & \quad + 0.5 \cdot P(W=1 \mid S=0,R=1) \bigg[ 0.8 \cdot P(S=0 \mid C=1) \\
 & \qquad + 0.2 P(S=0 \mid C=0) \bigg] \\
 & \quad + 0.5 \cdot P(W=1 \mid S=0,R=0) \bigg[ 0.2 \cdot P(S=0 \mid C=1) \\
 & \qquad + 0.8 \cdot P(S=0 \mid C=0) \bigg] \\
 & = 0.5 \cdot 0.99 \cdot ( 0.8 \cdot 0.1 + 0.2 \cdot 0.5 ) + 0.5 \cdot 0.9 \cdot ( 0.2 \cdot 0.1 + 0.8 \cdot 0.5 ) \\
 & \quad + 0.5 \cdot 0.9 \cdot ( 0.8 \cdot 0.9 + 0.2 \cdot 0.5 ) + 0.5 \cdot 0.0 \cdot ( 0.2 \cdot 0.9 + 0.8 \cdot 0.5 ) \\
 & = 0.2781 + 0.369 = 0.6471
\end{align}